# Angular ngrx store update on database change

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I am new to Angular and was exploring the following scenario.

E.g. Table A has a column named 'Arrived' of type Boolean. This flag is set by another client. Once the flag changes in the database, I want the change to be learnt by Ngrx Store and the new flag value be available in my client view. i.e. Once the store learns on the change in value in the database, an event can be dispatched to update the change in the view.

Any pointers please on how to update the Store upon a change in database?

Comment: The main question is how would you know if the database is changed? Are you implementing any websocket to an api, that sends you the updated data? Or, are you asking the api every so often to get the latest data?

Comment: The angular application can be open on several computers. A staff member can mark a customer "Arrived" once a customer has arrived in the waiting lounge. The ngrx/store will update the database (as side effects). Now I expect that all the other angular instances should to be able to learn of the changes in the value of the flag. I thought that there should be some mechanism by which Angular may be able to subscribe to changes in database rather than each client having to poll the database for changes (I guess the ngrx store is the source of truth only on each angular client instance)

Comment: The question still persists. Angular is frontend framework and runs of local browser. It cant simply update data to other instance, so you need some way to relay (or listen) to that update sitting on some db somewhere. An api or something similar is needed that angular can talk to is needed. If you have that, then we can say how angular will interact with that, and update the store or client view when things change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I am asking a very simple question. (A) I can refresh my Angular Frontend and get fresh data from the database. (B) I can have a push notification like solution on the backend that can send json updates to the angular frontend with new data as and when there are relevant changes in database, and that there are angular components interested in such data updates. There must be some solution to handle this basic requirement of Push Notification in Angular without which I don't see a reason why people use Ngrx/Store.

Comment: Sorry if i am being pedantic. Ngrx/Store is just a fancy/systematic way to maintain the local state. It cannot subscribe to db changes directly. You can use [RxJs](https://medium.com/briebug-blog/making-use-of-websockets-in-angular-way-easier-than-you-expected-25dd0061db1d) or something similar to maintain websocket connection to the push notification service(that talks to the db), and when the websocket fires back with update, you run appropriate action on the callback function that updates the store and re-renders your component.